# SPD workflow impersonation step, who counts as author?

Tags: designer-workflow

Impersonation Step quotes "The contents of this step will run as the workflow author"

Will impersonation steps run with the credentials of the person who publishes a workflow the **last** time?

If an author goes obsolete, hence their credentials become invalid, do all workflows need to be re-published by someone with appropriate permission level?

Comment: If the authors password expires would the workflow stop too? Or even if the authors password changes? If i decide to use a pecific acct for such workflows does this mean i would need to open the SPD using this credential and then publish the workflow?
Thans in Advance

Comment: Password changes/expires wouldn't stop a workflow. Changing permission of the user will. Disabling a user will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the Impersonation Step(s) will run as the last person who published the workflow, so you might have to republish them it the permissions of that person changes.

Or if possible create a User Account which is only used to publish workflows.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately a user account will not be provided, but I'll look into how workflows can be programmatically re-published.

Comment: Using a service account as @Per Jakobsen mentioned would save you a bunch of time. Programatically publishing a workflow seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: Thanks @iOnline247, the server administrators are not fond of creating service accounts, unfortunately.

Comment: That's a bad thing because service accounts make the most sense and on top of that are best practice. Sorry that you are a little handcuffed. :/